# How to create a border with space in the middle?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a border with a space in the middle of the top and bottom? I've attached an image to show what I'm referring to.
Maybe using ::before / ::after is how to achieve this?

Just after some advice.

[image]

Comment: add a box with white background in the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
button{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid brown;
  position:relative;
  background:none;
 }
 
 button::before{
  content:"";
  width:25px;
  height:calc(100% + 5.5px);
  background-color:#fff;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  
 }
 
 button span{
  font-size:18px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index:3;
 }
```

```html
<button>
  <span>Click Me</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Your code has a bug, When i click on your button, It show's a border under your button!

Comment: the person will figure it out, thanks BTW

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this by using `::after` & `::before`. just look at my snippet example and tell me if is that your answer or not?

```css
.button.button1 {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
position: relative
}

.button {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    color: 4CAF50;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.button1::after {

  content: "";
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
width: 5px;
    height: 2px;
    top: -2px;
    right: 45%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.button.button1::before {

  content: "";
position: absolute;
background-color: white;
width: 5px;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 45%;
    bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button button1">Green</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use  gradient and a transparent border :

```css
h1 {
  /* draw the border */
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to left, #cea87c 45%, #cea87c00 45%, #cea87c00 55%, #cea87c 55%);
  
  /* make it shrink & center */
  width:max-content;
  margin:1em auto;
  padding:0.25em 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>All Projects</h1>
<h1>All Projects really ?</h1>
```

Comment: also like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f5Lmo471/ to have a transparent background

Answer (score -1):

use :before :after for buttons.. and shape them according to your need.